# ios, how do I send an asynchronous notification to a seperate VC?

Tags: objective-c, sockets, asynchronous

Right now I am using NSNotificationCenter to send synchronous notifications from my socket singleton to a view controller. However, this is causing problems. Upon viewDidAppear, my observers are not receiving notifications when they should. How can I do this asynchronously? I managed to get the VC to become populated with data from my socket by posting a notification in my VC's viewDidLoad, but this dosnt seem like the right thing to do.

How my app works, I emit data to the socket, and the socket gives a call back called "initialize", upon this notification, I push to a new VC. Might this be causing the problem?

```
-(void)receiveInitializeNotification:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSetListRoomVC" sender:self];
    });
}
```

Current CODE:Socket

```
- (void)startSocketWithHost:(NSString *)host;{

    [SIOSocket socketWithHost:host response:^(SIOSocket *socket) {

        self.socket = socket;


        //Send a message to RoomCode controler to notify the reciever that the user has enetered a correct code and can enter the specific setList room.
        [self.socket on:@"initialize" callback:^(NSArray *args) {

            NSDictionary *socketIdDict = [args objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *socketID = [socketIdDict objectForKey:@"socket"];
            self.socketID = socketID;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"initialize" object:nil];

        }];

        //on Callback for events related to updates with the song queue.
        [self.socket on:@"q_update_B" callback:^(NSArray *args) {

            NSLog(@"qUpdateB has been emitted");
            NSArray *tracks = [args objectAtIndex:0];
            self.setListTracks = tracks;

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postQUpdateBNotification) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES] ;
        }];

        [self.socket on:@"current_artist_B" callback:^(NSArray *args) {

            self.currentArtist = [args objectAtIndex:0];

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postCurrentArtistBNotification) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES] ;

        }];
```

Receiving the "initialize" notification.

```
-(void)receiveInitializeNotification:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSetListRoomVC" sender:self];
}
```

Receiving qUpdateB in SetListVC

```
- (void)receiveUpdateBNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Recieved update B");
    NSArray *recievedtracks = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]setListTracks];
    self.tracks = recievedtracks;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

My "qUpdateB has been emmited" gets called upon segue to new VC.
However, the notification is not received in the new VC. 
If I add

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"currentArtistB" object:nil];
```

To my SetlistVC along with the observer then it will work as intended, but this dosnt seem right.

Comment: I highly doubt you really need an async method, but have you looked at the `dispatch_async` method?

Comment: I updated my question with more details, you might be right. It may be with how I am pushing to the new VC that is causing problems. Thoughts? @CanPoyrazoğlu

Comment: You should make sure that your view controller has registered the notification before posting "initialize".

Comment: Ya, that is the problem. I'll mark your answer as correct. @KudoCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is working on the network thread, isn't it ? If you post the notification in that thread, the receiver will get the notification on the network thread. However you can only operate UI on the main thread. So your really need is post the notification on the main thread, in that way your view controller can receive the notification on the main thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postNotification) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES] ;

- (void)postNotification {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"yourEventName" object:self] ;
}
```

Comment: Actually, It works now, but there is a delay of 5-10 seconds.

Comment: now it is a 2-3 second delay. hmm, perhaps it is server side issue. But that was definitely the answer. thank you.

Comment: @Andy It seems impossible to me unless the main thread is busy with other things , you should avoid that.

Comment: How can i see if the main thread is busy with other things? I dont know why it would be. It has completely stopped working now. code is exactly the same.

Comment: @Andy I think the issue comes from the server, make sure that you have got the response from server.

Comment: I dont think that is it. My original code had postNotifcation inside viewDidLoad, AND in my singleton, and it would load the data instantly.

Comment: I get the NSLog from my socket instantly, the notification takes more time.

Comment: Before the first time you post the notification, has the view controller registered itself as the observer?